# Concatenate double pointer char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, char, double-pointer

There are many questions about how to concatenate char array in C, but what I want to know is different from that. I would like to know how to concatenate "double pointer" char array in C.

For example,

```
const char *array1[] = {"aa", "bb"};
const char *array2[] = {"cc", "dd", "ee"};
```

I want to get the new double pointer array of char like this:

```
char **new_array = {"aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee"};
// this code actually doesn't work, though
```

I want to know the simplest and fastest way to realize this.

EDIT: In fact, I am planning to create a program below.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    pid_t pid;
    char **args = {"sh", "-c"} + argv; // this code doesn't work
    posix_spawn(&pid, "/bin/sh", NULL, NULL, (char* const*)args, NULL);
}
```

This program just passes arguments after "sh -c".

Comment: We need some context i think. Are these runtime strings? If not, you have the quickest way. Just write it.

Comment: There is no standard function like `strcat` for combining generic arrays. You need to do it manually.

Comment: I've added the detail context. I want to add "sh", "-c" argument before the original arguments (argv**).

Comment: Simply make an array of pointers. Have the two first pointers point at string literals and the rest to each item in argv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just allocate a buffer for that

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
int main()
{
    #define ARRAY_SIZE(x)  (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]))
    const char * const array1[] = {"aa", "bb"};
    const size_t array1_size = ARRAY_SIZE(array1);
    const char * const array2[] = {"cc", "dd", "ee"};
    const size_t array2_size = ARRAY_SIZE(array2);
    const size_t concat_len = array1_size + array2_size;

    const char ** const concat = malloc(concat_len * sizeof(*concat));
    assert(concat != NULL);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < concat_len; ++i) {
        consr char *string_to_copy = i < array1_size ? array1[i] : array2[i - array1_size];
        concat[i] = strdup(string_to_copy);
        assert(concat[i] != NULL);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < concat_len; ++i) {
        printf("concat[%zu] = (%zu) '%s'\n", i, strlen(concat[i]), concat[i]);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < concat_len; ++i) {
        free(concat[i]);
    }
    free(concat);

    return 0;
}
```

But we should be able to do better.

Comment: It worked! If no better answer comes up, this is temporarily the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    const char *array1[] = {"aa", "bb"};
    const char *array2[] = {"cc", "dd", "ee"};


    int arraySize1 = (sizeof(array1)/sizeof(char*));
    int arraySize2 = (sizeof(array2)/sizeof(char*));
    char **resultArr = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*(arraySize1+arraySize2));
    int i =0;

   /* copy array1*/
    for(i=0;i<arraySize1;i++)
   {
      resultArr[i] = malloc(strlen(array1[i]) +1);
      strcpy(resultArr[i], array1[i]);
   }

   /*copy array2*/
   for(i=0;i<arraySize2;i++)
   {
      resultArr[arraySize1+i] = malloc(strlen(array2[i])+1);
      strcpy(resultArr[arraySize1+i], array2[i]);
   }

    /*print resulting array*/
     for(i=0;i<arraySize1+arraySize2;i++)
     {
        printf("%s ", *(resultArr+i));
     }
 }
```

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(array1[i]))` ?? If you initialise with some decent length strings the program crashes.

Comment: . . . because `sizeof(array1[i])` is the size of a pointer, not the length of a string.

Comment: Yes I got it, that was typo.